# React Native Navigating have some problem on iOS

Tags: react-native, react-native-navigation

I have some problems with my React Navigating, I found cannot navigate on the child page in iOS, and Android is working.

Start>Home>Page1>Home

I use Navigation.goBack on Page1 via `TouchableOpacity`

On Android it's OK, it retune to the Home Page, But on iOS, it will close the app.

I need to change to use push instead of `navigation.navigate`

Start>Home via navigation.push("Page1") >via navigation.push("Home")

I would like to ask if I did something wrong.

Comment: This post needs more details and clarity. Like the crash details on iOS.